# How to find the marginal density here in the question given?

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $Y$ have a uniform distribution on the interval $(0, 1)$, and let the conditional density of $X$ given $Y = y$ be uniform on the interval from $0$ to $\sqrt{y}$. What is the marginal density of $X$ for $0 < x < 1$?

Comment: Do share your thoughts on the problem; posting the problem statement only is discouraged.

Answer (score -1):

Given $$Y=U(0,1)$$
$$f_{X/Y=y}(x|y)=\begin{cases}
 1/\sqrt{y}, & 0<x<\sqrt{y}\\    
  0, & otherwise   
\end{cases} $$ 
Using Conditional probability, $$f_X(x)=f_{X/Y=y}(x|y).f_Y(y)$$
Therefore, $$f_X(x)=\begin{cases}
 1/\sqrt{y}, & 0<x<1\\    
  0, & otherwise   
\end{cases}$$